# Renaming text files based on the first word in the file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I found many similar examples but not this exact goal. I have a fairly large number of text files that all have a similar first word (clipxx) where xx is a different number in each file.

I want to rename each file using the first word in the file. Here is what I have tried using Powershell. I get an error that I cannot call a method on a null valued expression.

```
Get-ChildItem *.avs | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item = Get-Content ($line.Split(" "))[0] }
```

Comment: So to be clear, if you have a file named `clip42` containing the text `Hello world`, it would be renamed to `Hello`?  (And if so, how would you handle multiple files that contain the same first word?)

Comment: What you've written makes no sense. `Rename-Item` is a cmdlet, you can't use `=` to set a value to it. `Get-Content` needs the name of the file to get content from, which you aren't giving it. `$line` doesn't just appear from nowhere, and there's nowhere in your code which gives it any value. The error comes from this - `$line.Split()` when `$line` hasn't been given a value. You want something like `Get-ChildItem *.avs | Rename-Item -NewName { (Get-Content -Literalpath $_.FullName | Select-Object -first 1).Split(' ')[0] }` (untested)

Comment: Sorry, no. Right now the file name is just numeric (25.avs). I want the name to be clip42 (using your example) which is the first word in the file. The number 42 changes in each file but they all have clipxx as the first word,

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this in three parts:

1. Get the list of files you want to change.
2. Create and map the new name for each file.
3. Rename the files.

phase-1: get the list of files you want to change.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem *.avs
```

phase-2: map the file name to a new name

```
$file_map = @()
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $file_map += @{
        OldName = $file.Fullname
        NewName = "{0}.avs" -f $(Get-Content $file.Fullname| select -First 1)
    }
}
```

phase-3: make the name change

```
$file_map | % { Rename-Item -Path $_.OldName -NewName $_.NewName }
```

Changing things in a list that you're enumerating can be tricky. That's why I recommend breaking this up.

Here is me running this on my machine...

[image]

And, here is what was in my files...

[image]

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you. Forgive me as I am a complete novice, but how do I run this? Do I put all this in a batch file and run the file? I don't know how to execute this so if you could clarify that I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Open a new Powershell session. Navigate (in your Powershell session) to the folder with the *.avs files. Copy and paste the code from phase-1 into the session. Copy and past the code from phase-2. Before you copy and paste the code for phase-3, you can see what will change to what by typing `$file_map`. If that looks good, copy and past the code from phase-3. That should be it. :-)

Comment: Or write it all together in a .ps1 file and run that in powershell.

Comment: it seems to have worked but it did not carry over the file extension (*.avs). So now I need a way to rename them all with that extension. ; )

Comment: Hmm. That's weird. I wonder what went wrong. I just tried this on some sample files, and it worked. You can get at the file with `Get-ChildItem clip*` assuming files in the directory didn't start with "clip". I'd probably just do `ls clip* | % { Rename-Item -NewName "${_}.avs" }`, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: I was able to change the extensions so it worked in the end. Thanks again.

Comment: Kewl. I updated my post with screen shots of me running everything. If you know what went sideways, post it. I don't want some random internet searcher grabbing something that didn't work.