# How to rename all files in directory based on contents of the 2nd line [POWERSHELL]

Tags: powershell, batch-rename

How to make this script read the second line on text in each file(s) in the directory recursively, and rename the file itself according to the contents of line #2?

This script was found here:
[Renaming text files based on the first word in the file in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029187/renaming-text-files-based-on-the-first-word-in-the-file-in-powershell)

The script renames only the very first file in the folder using the first line of text, below are the top two lines of text in the file:
sample name O123456.NT; wanted rename to: **O14294 (CXP-14294).NT**

line 1: %

line 2: **O14294 (CXP-14294)**

...
... rest of file hundreds of lines long etc

```
$files = Get-ChildItem *.NT


$file_map = @()
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $file_map += @{
        OldName = $file.Fullname
        NewName = "{0}.NT" -f $(Get-Content $file.Fullname| select -First 2)
    }
}

$file_map | % { Rename-Item -Path $_.OldName -NewName $_.NewName }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, getting the second line by indexing:

```
$files = (Get-ChildItem -path G:\Test -Filter *.ng).FullName

foreach ($File in $Files) {

  $MyName = (get-content -Path "$File")[1] + ".ng"
  Rename-Item -Path "$File" -NewName "$MyName"

}
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

This can be done a little more succinctly by just working with the name instead of full name. The trick to getting just the second line from the file is to skip one, *then* take just one.

So:

```
    Get-ChildItem *nt |
    ForEach-Object{
        $oldname = $_.name;
        $newname = "{0}.nt" -f $(Get-Content $oldname | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1);
        Rename-Item -Path $oldname -NewName $newname
    }
```